# How do I validate a input-text field in an Apex Repeat tag by alerting on click of a button if its empty or not?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

TEXT FIELD:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!TransTerms }" var="tms" id="repeatTag" rendered="{!showApproval && readOnly == false}">

  <div class="textinput" id="inner-div-tc">
 <apex:inputText value="{!tms.KAM_Remarks__c }" html-placeholder="Type here to add any remark/s." />
```

/* BUTTON

```
<span class="approvebtn">
 <apex:commandLink value="Submit for Approval" style="{!If(readOnly == true ,'pointer-events: none; background:#b7b7b7; color:#d7d7d7;','')}" styleClass="btn-normal-new" action="{!submitForApproval}" rendered="{!showApproval}"  onclick="approveValidate()" />
 </span>
```

*/

SCRIPT:

```
function approveValidate() {

var m = $(".textinput").val();
          if(m == ' ')
         {

event.preventDefault();
return false;
               }                           
else
 { return true;}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m = $(".textinput").val();
```

the above will not be a valid statement as this will reference all the elems of that class...

instead you can reference a single instance of a dom element by its Id. this can be provided by using the below

```
var m=document.getelementbyid('{!$Component.repeatTag.**i**.input textID}').value;
```

where **i** is the iteration number for the repeat block starting from 0.

if the above throws an error, provide the Complete Id in the format

```
var m=document.getelementbyid('parentId:repeatTag:**i**:inoutTextboxId').value;
```

This way you can get the value of the input text box and then check if it has value, then proceed to submit action.